# How to get the second key inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an HTML template and a JSON array. I need to separate each product into e separate HTML file. To do that I created a Download button that gets the name of each product - For example it gets product1.html as the first downloaded file and etc. 
My problem is that my JS code only gets the first key. When it reaches it I need to get the second key as a tab name(example - overview, features etc.) and the content (value) that is inside. 
I need this only for me because I have to run more than 20 JSON files with almost the same code but different CSS rather than creating manually HTML files.

```js
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}

const openDiv = (evt, divName) => {
    // Declare all variables
    let i, tabContent, tabLinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabContent" and hide them
    tabContent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabContent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
        tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tabLinks" and remove the class "active"
    tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabLinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
        tabLinks[i].className = tabLinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }       

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(divName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

};
const appendData = data => {
    let tab = document.getElementById("tab-container");
    let overviewContainer = document.getElementById("overview-container"),
        featuresContainer = document.getElementById("features-container"),
        requirementsContainer = document.getElementById("requirements-container"),
        galleryContainer = document.getElementById("gallery-container");   
    let mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer"); 

    Object.entries(data).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key[0]);

        if (key !== undefined) {
            Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                if (key === 'overview') {
                    tab.innerHTML += `
                        <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'overview');" id="defaultOpen">Overview</button>
                    `;
                                                        
                    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                overviewContainer.innerHTML += `
                    <h3 class="h3">${value[i].heading}</h3>
                    <p class="par">${value[i].paragraph.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")}</p>
                `;
            }
                } else if (key === 'features') {
                    tab.innerHTML += `
                        <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'features')">Features</button>
                    `; 

                    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                featuresContainer.innerHTML +=  `
                    <h3 class="h3">${value[i].heading}</h3>
                    <ul class="listStyle">
                        <li>${value[i].list.replace(/\n/g, "<li>")}</li>
                    </ul>
                `;
            }
                }else if (key === 'requirements') {
                    tab.innerHTML += `
                        <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'requirements')">Requirements</button>
                    `;        
                    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                requirementsContainer.innerHTML +=  `
                    <h3 class="h3">${value[i].heading}</h3>
                    <p class="par">${value[i].paragraph.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")}</p>
                    <ul class="listStyle">
                        <li>${value[i].list.replace(/\n/g, "<li>")}</li>
                    </ul>
                `;         
            }
                } else if (key === 'gallery') {
                    tab.innerHTML += `
                        <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'gallery')">Gallery</button>
                    `;
                    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    
                        galleryContainer.innerHTML +=   `
                            <div class="slideshow">                             
                                <div class="mySlides fade">
                                    <img src="${value[i].url}"  class="imageSlide"></a>
                                </div>
                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                            </div>
                        `;       
                    }
                }
            });
                function download(filename, text) {
                    const element = document.createElement('a');
                    
                    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
                    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
            
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(element);
            
                    element.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(element);
                }      
                document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    download(key[0] + ".html", mainContainer.innerHTML);  
                        
                }, false);   
        };
    })
}

ready(() => {

fetch("https://extendsclass.com/api/json-storage/bin/eaeaeea")
.then (response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then (data => {
    appendData(data);
    document.querySelector("#defaultOpen").click();
    showSlides(slideIndex);
})
.catch(err => {
    return console.log(err);
});

});
```

```css
/* Gallery Style */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.imageSlide {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #d1143e;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #212529;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active2, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #d1143e;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Paragraphs and Headings */
.h3 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.par {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Tabs */
.tab {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabLinks {
    border: 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.tabLinks:hover, .tabLinks:active {
    color: rgb(209, 20, 62);
}

.tabContent {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* List style */
.listStyle {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.listStyle li::before {
    content: "•";
    color: rgb(209, 20, 62);
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="tab-container">
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'overview');" id="defaultOpen">Overview</button>
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'features')">Features</button>
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'requirements')">Requirements</button>
            <button class="tabLinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'gallery')">Gallery</button>
        </div>
     
        <div class="tabContent" id="overview">
            <div id="overview-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="tabContent" id="features">
            <div id="features-container">
            </div>    
        </div>

        <div class="tabContent" id="specs">
            <div id="specs-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="tabContent" id="requirements">
            <div id="requirements-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="gallery" class="tabContent">
            <div id="gallery-container">       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="download">DOWNLOAD</button>
```

Comment: You might find it easier to find an answer if you realize that you're dealing with an array of objects, not a "JSON array". JSON is a text format, and once you get into the `then(data => ... )`, it's no longer JSON.

Comment: And this is absolutely not a [**minimal**, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide an example of the data returned by the server.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope that's better.
The code in the snippet is the same as on my Visual basic but here Google Chrome blocks the automatic download and only downloads the first file. I don't know why is that since when I run through it normally it downloads all three files.